# Why do I get an error when adding an icon on react-native?

Tags: react-native

The error is: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got number.

I did exactly same work two days ago. I got it run. But this time I couldnt.

I run these codes to get the icon run;

```
npm install react-native-svg --save
npm install react-native-svg-transformer --save
react-native link react-native-svg
```

Here is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Application from "./src/components/icons/application.svg"


const App  = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Application height={30} width={22} fill={"#8c3bff"} style={{ backgroundColor: "#8c3bff" }} />

      </View>    
    </SafeAreaView>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
  }
});

export default App;
```

this is application.svg , I thought this could work, but it doesnt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 463 463" style="enable-background:new 0 0 463 463;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M175.5,0h-136C17.72,0,0,17.72,0,39.5v136C0,197.28,17.72,215,39.5,215h136c21.78,0,39.5-17.72,39.5-39.5v-136
        C215,17.72,197.28,0,175.5,0z M200,175.5c0,13.509-10.991,24.5-24.5,24.5h-136C25.991,200,15,189.009,15,175.5v-136
        C15,25.991,25.991,15,39.5,15h136c13.509,0,24.5,10.991,24.5,24.5V175.5z"/>
    <path d="M423.5,0h-136C265.72,0,248,17.72,248,39.5v136c0,21.78,17.72,39.5,39.5,39.5h136c21.78,0,39.5-17.72,39.5-39.5v-136
        C463,17.72,445.28,0,423.5,0z M448,175.5c0,13.509-10.991,24.5-24.5,24.5h-136c-13.509,0-24.5-10.991-24.5-24.5v-136
        c0-13.509,10.991-24.5,24.5-24.5h136c13.509,0,24.5,10.991,24.5,24.5V175.5z"/>
    <path d="M175.5,248h-136C17.72,248,0,265.72,0,287.5v136C0,445.28,17.72,463,39.5,463h136c21.78,0,39.5-17.72,39.5-39.5v-136
        C215,265.72,197.28,248,175.5,248z M200,423.5c0,13.509-10.991,24.5-24.5,24.5h-136C25.991,448,15,437.009,15,423.5v-136
        c0-13.509,10.991-24.5,24.5-24.5h136c13.509,0,24.5,10.991,24.5,24.5V423.5z"/>
    <path d="M423.5,248h-136c-21.78,0-39.5,17.72-39.5,39.5v136c0,21.78,17.72,39.5,39.5,39.5h136c21.78,0,39.5-17.72,39.5-39.5v-136
        C463,265.72,445.28,248,423.5,248z M448,423.5c0,13.509-10.991,24.5-24.5,24.5h-136c-13.509,0-24.5-10.991-24.5-24.5v-136
        c0-13.509,10.991-24.5,24.5-24.5h136c13.509,0,24.5,10.991,24.5,24.5V423.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: could you add the application.svg too

Comment: Sure, I added the svg file

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
We should add this code in metro.config.js, then it works.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```